# Logging error, argument error TypeError when running the logger

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, arguments, typeerror

When I tried to make keyboard logger this error appeared every time I pressed a key (in this case it's d). Below is my code and here is my error log:

> ```
> --- Logging error ---
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1025, in emit
>     msg = self.format(record)
>   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 869, in format
>     return fmt.format(record)
>   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 611, in format
>     s = self.formatMessage(record)
>   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 580, in formatMessage
>     return self._style.format(record)
>   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 422, in format
>     return self._fmt % record.__dict__
> TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
> Call stack:
>   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
>     self._bootstrap_inner()
>   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
>     self.run()
>   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 144, in run
>     self._run()
>   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\win32.py", line 353, in _run
>     self._process(msg.wParam, msg.lParam)
>   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 162, in inner
>     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 240, in _process
>     self.on_press(key)
>   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 78, in inner
>     if f(*args) is False:
>   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Random programs\Keyloggar.pyw", line 11, in on_press
>     logging.info(key)
> Message: 'd'
> Arguments: ()
> ```

This is  my code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

#Defining the directory as well as the key strokes
log_dir = "C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup/"
logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir+"key_logger.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format = '% 
(asctime)s:%s(messages)')

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(key)
#Giving access of me to myself
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as Listener:
    Listener.join()
```

Could someone tell me what I did wrong? Did  I import the module wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your logging format is wrong.

Just replace `format = '% (asctime)s:%s(messages)'` by `format='%(asctime)s:%(message)s'`